# In French, what is the meaning of « de service » in the expression « passer pour la rabat-joie de service »?

Tags: expressions

> Je vais passer pour la rabat-joie ***de service***, mais je crois qu'on aurait dû faire ...

I usually use « rabat-joie » without the phrase « de service »:

> Sans vouloir jouer les rabats-joie, je ...

What does « de service » add to the meaning of this sentence? Is it like "a ***chronic*** rabat-joie"?

Comment: Kind of, possibly with the original meaning of "chronic", but now in French, "chronique" is associated with illnesses and mostly used for negative/destructive habits rather that simply annoying behaviors. But you got the idea !

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Ja, "chronic" might have been a bit over the top! "Perpetual wet-blanketing", perhaps?

Comment: "de service" has an idea of "*always there when you need it*" rather than "*perpetual*". The [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/service) says "*Se dit du rôle que l'on est couramment amené à jouer aux yeux des autres.*"

Comment: @TeleportingGoat I see. How about "a wet blanket, always at your service!"? Sarcastically, of course.

Comment: It's not about being "at your service" ^^ Être "au service [de quelqu'un]" means helping and serving them, but "être **de** service" means "doing your job/doing your shift".

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Oh, I was actually just cracking a joke about the English expression "at your service". ;) Like "Call me whenever you need someone  to spoil the occasion. I'm always at your service for it!".

Comment: Sorry I really didn't get that ^^ I didn't know where the wet blanket came from and "at your service" also exists in French so I just thought you didn't get it right

Comment: @TeleportingGoat I'm not sure if it's translated like this in a dictionary, but I tend to associate "rabat-joie" with "a wet blanket", that is, "a buzz-killing person". ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

« *Le X de service* » est quelqu'un dont le rôle est X. L'expression implique que cette personne fait X et rien d'autre. L'expression est en général ironique : elle met l'accent sur le fait que cette personne fait X, et résume toutes ses actions à X.

Par exemple, « la rabat-joie de service » est une personne qui est rabat-joie, c'est-à-dire qu'elle dit quelque chose qui déplaît aux autres. Par rapport à « je vais passer pour une rabat-joie », dire « je vais passer pour la rabat-joie de service » implique que ce que la personne va dire peut être réduit au rôle de rabat-joie, sans regarder plus loin. La personne qui dit cela s'attend à ce que ce qu'elle va dire ensuite soit perçu comme négatif, et soit ignoré à cause de cela. Donc « Je vais passer pour la rabat-joie de service, mais … » est à peu près synonyme de « Je sais que vous n'allez pas aimer ce que je vais dire, mais [vous devriez quand même y faire attention :] … ».

On peut utiliser l'expression avec toutes sortes de rôles.

> On dirait que c'est lui le chef ! On voit bien que c'est ton préféré, moi je ne suis que l'abruti de service !   [(Muriel Derome, *Parents heureux = enfants heureux*)](https://books.google.fr/books?id=N43_CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT24&dq=%22l%27abruti+de+service%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y)

→ « Moi, tu ne me vois que comme un abruti. »

> je pensais que tu étais un peu la bonne âme de service.   [(M.G. Reyes, *Émancipés*)](https://books.google.fr/books?id=oKRJDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT165&dq=%22la+bonne+%C3%A2me+de+service%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22la%20bonne%20%C3%A2me%20de%20service%22&f=false)

→ « je pensais que tu étais toujours gentil et qu'on ne voyait que ça de toi »

> je n'étais pas le seul candidat contre mon challenger socialiste. Il y avait le communiste de service mais aussi …   [(Jean-Claude Gaudin, *Une Passion nommée Marseille*)](https://books.google.fr/books?id=If0hAQAAIAAJ&q=%22le+communiste+de+service%22&dq=%22le+communiste+de+service%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y)

→ il y avait un communiste parce que le parti communiste envoie un candidat même si c'est pour la forme

Cette expression n'implique pas forcément qu'une même personne fait souvent X. Dans la phrase de la question, la personne n'est une rabat-joie qu'à ce moment. Dans les exemples de l'abruti et de la bonne âme, la personne a souvent ces rôles, mais c'est impliqué par le contexte, pas par l'utilisation de l'expression « le X de service ». Dans l'exemple du communiste, il y a toujours un candidat communiste, qui l'est de façon très visible voir stéréotypique, mais ce n'est pas forcément la même personne d'une élection à l'autre.

Étymologiquement, cette expression vient d'expressions comme « l'officier de service », « le garde de service », « le réceptionniste de service », etc. Une personne est *de service* quand elle assure le rôle à ce moment. Suivant l'heure, une personne différente est l'officier, le garde, le réceptionniste, etc. Pendant qu'elle a ce rôle, la personne est assimilée au rôle : l'officier de service commande jusqu'à la fin de son service.

Answer (score 2):

L'expression « de service » est une expression ironique qui signifie que la personne dont on parle intervient régulièrement de cette façon et on s'attend à ce qu'elle agisse toujours dans ce rôle.

Ce n'est donc pas spécifique au « rabat-joie de service ».

> Dans ce film, le personnage qui s'impose naturellement est celui de l'idiot, mais pas n'importe quel idiot, l'« idiot de service », le groom qui est au service. (*[Éclats de rire - Variations sur le corps comique](https://books.google.fr/books?id=eWkmDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT127&lpg=PT127&dq=%22idiot%20de%20service%22&source=bl&ots=B5aVlsKor5&sig=Je2vlG7U-52MPppLSfCKkP_2ToY&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV0eSNzd7UAhUG1BoKHctUDmcQ6AEISDAH#v=onepage&q=%22idiot%20de%20service%22&f=false)* - Olivier Mongin, 2017)

> Et vous verrez, quand la bonne poire de service se met à jouer à ce même jeu avec les autres, elle devient étrangement bien moins sollicitée… (Sur un blog, [10 astuces pour arrêter d’être une bonne poire](http://www.fourchette-et-bikini.fr/bien-etre/10-astuces-pour-arreter-detre-une-bonne-poire-39061.html))

Comment: So is it like "A chronic rabat-joie, at your service!"? haha

Comment: As an attempt at self-deprecating humour, can you say "Sans vouloir jouer les rabats-joie ***de service***, je ..."?

Comment: @Alone-zee "Chronic" is more *invétéré* or *incorrigible*, like in "he's a chronic liar / smoker" *c'est un menteur/fumeur invétèré*. I don't feel "chronic" has the same connotations. Yes, of course you can use the word as attempt at self-deprecating humour, *Je sais que je suis la moralisatrice de service, mais je voudrais vous rappeler que...*

Comment: @Alone-zee The nearest I can think of in English is "I know I'll sound as the  usual killjoy but..."

Comment: "The town [+ whatever]" (granted,  most often used with "drunk") maybe kinda captures it in English. @Alone-zee

Comment: Non, le X de service n'est pas forcément un X chronique. Elle peut tout à fait être X ponctuellement. Ce qui compte, c'est qu'elle fasse X à ce moment précis, et qu'on la réduit à au rôle de X.

Comment: For example you can say "le Noir de service" when talking about a black character in a movie who seems to be here because "hey there must be a black character in a movie".

Answer (score 1):

> Je vais passer pour le rabat-joie **de service**.

can be translated to

> I'm going to sound like the **on-duty** killjoy.